# "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad."

Tags: android, admob

Have tried so many things. Wasted a day on something that seems so easy.
When I open up my app, the ads don't show.

Everything works without error but just the ads don't show at all.

Code and logcat as follows

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "***");


    // " *** " is replacement for AdID and AdunitID
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("45051C497E3954E140EC02E9C7B31B3C")
            .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context="a1440.MainActivity"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize = "BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId= "******"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
```

Logcat:

```
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a    connection for the pid: 16437

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application    Cache with manifest       
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache",    source:       htt://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html    (0) 

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event",    source:       htt://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html    (0) 

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event",    source:       htt://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html    (0) 

I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. I/Ads: Scheduling ad    refresh 60000 milliseconds from now. I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not       refreshing ad. 

I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from      now.
```

Comment: Are you sure you're making calls like `adView.onResume()`, `onPause()`, etc in MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a left and right padding for your `RelativeLayout`. This is almost certainly leaving too little horizontal room for your AdView.

Comment: That is a very clever guess , but no , still doesnt work. I tried to make it in a fresh dummy project and still the ad wasnt visible. I have installed play services and everything.

Comment: Did you remove all padding from `RelativeLayout` and `AdView`?

Comment: yes I did. No padding. I even removed the imageview that was above it just to be sure.

Comment: There is no ImageViewer in your layout above. If you don't tell us everything we can't help you.